# Xamarin iOS application with dynamic framework which depends on static library

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm building iOS dynamic framework. Lets call it Foo.framework. I also have binding for this framework.
This framework depends on Objective-C static library (libBar.a). 
Now I dont't want to link libBar.a with Foo.framework in order to avoid possible duplicate symbols when consumer of the framework would link with libBar.a directly or via other framework.

In native applications I achieve this by linking libBar.a directly in top-level application along with Foo.framework.
However when doing the same in Xamarin project symbols from libBar.a are getting stripped from the resulting binary in Release configuration.

How could I avoid these symbols being stripped?

Comment: i'm not too sure about this, but if this is to do with linking you can select option 'Don't link' for the release configuration, more info here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/
I know the preserve attribute stops methods/classes from being stripped, but not sure if that'll help you. This link may be more use for your use case: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

Comment: @MattjeS thank you for your answer. The reason I believe it's the linking issue is the Debug version working fine, but Release doesn't. I've tried "Don't Link" option, but it doesn't help

Comment: I haven't done this so I'm not sure I can help you, my only suggestion is if you are using code like: `[DllImport (Constants.UIKitLibrary,EntryPoint="CLibrary")]
public extern static void MethodInCLibrary();` you could try adding the `[Preserve]` attribute which will force it to not be stripped. You may not be accessing libBar.a in that way. I've had issues with having override methods being stripped out in the past and the linker has had many issues before.., changing the linking option, clean, rebuild and then changing it back and then clean, rebuild normally fixed it for me